Weight Painting CPU utilization is low
Does anyone have an idea why my CPU is only being used <40% for weight painting?
I have confirmed in the resource monitor that Blender is using all of my cores equally (good), but under 40% for weight painting.
Most geometry is hidden in viewport.
All modifiers are disabled.
The left side of the graph below is my CPU utilization when weight painting a character of 250,000 quads. Performance is not good & it's really slowing down my process. My PC is capable of handling the task, but the CPU is being under utilized.
On the right side of the graph is a Cycles GPU render. No problem hitting 100% CPU utilization.


